# Java ASM "Type top (current frame, locals[0]) is not assignable to reference type"

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I’m currently developing a java add-on for a minecraft client called "LabyMod". Because Labymod did not create all events I need I'm trying to create the missing event myself.
For this I need to modify a class via asm but every time I make the modifications to this class I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to launch
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:131)
at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Exception Details:
Location:
aip.a(Laed;Lakb;)Ljava/util/List; @1909: aload_0
Reason:
Type top (current frame, locals[0]) is not assignable to reference type
Current Frame:
bci: @1909
flags: { }
locals: { top, top, top, 'java/util/ArrayList' }
stack: { 'java/util/ArrayList' }
```

You can view my code here, all class and method names I transform are right because if I remove both "ALOAD" (and remove the required parameters of course) it works

```
public byte[] transform(String name, String transformedName, byte[] basicClass) {
        if (implementation == null) {
            return basicClass;
        }
        if (transformedName.equals(implementation.getTooltipClassName()) || transformedName.length() > 0) {
            ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
            ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(basicClass);
            classReader.accept(classNode, 0);
            methodFor: for (MethodNode methodNode : classNode.methods) {

                if (methodNode.name.equals(implementation.getTooltipMethodName())) {

                    if (methodNode.desc.equals(implementation.getTooltipMethodDesc())) {
                        System.out.println("M:" + methodNode.name);
                        System.out.println("D: " + methodNode.desc);
                        for (int i = 0; i < methodNode.instructions.size(); i++) {
                            AbstractInsnNode node = methodNode.instructions.get(i);
                            if (node.getOpcode() == Opcodes.ARETURN) {
                                System.out.println("Method found");
                                AbstractInsnNode eventHook = new MethodInsnNode(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC,
                                        "org/forengoetter/eventhandler/EventAdapter", "onItemTooltip",
                                        implementation.getTooltipEventMethodDesc(), false);
                                AbstractInsnNode loadHook = new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
                                AbstractInsnNode loadHookAdvanced = new VarInsnNode(Opcodes.ALOAD, 2);
                                methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(node, loadHook);
                                System.out.println("hook1");
                                methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(node, loadHookAdvanced);
                                System.out.println("hook2");
                                methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(node, eventHook);
                                System.out.println("hook3");
                                break methodFor;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
            classNode.accept(classWriter);
            return classWriter.toByteArray();
        }
        return basicClass;
    }
```

this is the method which should be called:

```
public static List<String> onItemTooltip(List<String> toolTip, ItemStack itemStack, ITooltipFlag advanced) {
        ItemTooltipEvent event = new ItemTooltipEvent(itemStack, toolTip, advanced.isAdvanced());
        // FOG.getInstance().getEventBus().post(event);
        event.toolTip.add("this is a test");
        return event.toolTip;

    }
```

and this is the signature of this method I'm using in the asm transformation `(Ljava/util/List;Laip;Lakb;)Ljava/util/List;` (the signature is obfuscated because of minecraft, but the class names are right, I've checked it several times)

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: According to the `VerifyError`, the two variables you are trying to read do not contain usable values. The reason why the verifier thinks so, lies in something happening before the `areturn` instruction. It might be correct that these variables contain the expected values at method entry, as derived from the method signature, but that doesn’t imply that this still is the case at method exit. Ordinary Java code (i.e. generated by `javac`) keeps its parameter variables valid throughout the entire method, but when the signature is obfuscated, why not the bytecode as well…